# could not figure out the error in this teradata script

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

Script is as follows:

```
SELECT
   CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(ABU_PTY_CD),4,2) AS CHAR(2)) ABU_PTY_CD,
   ACCTG_PRD_YR_CD,
   ACCTG_PRD_MO_CD ,

   CASE 
       WHEN (OUDS_FAC_CD > ' ' ) THEN CAST (SUBSTR(OUDS_FAC_CD, 1, 5) AS CHAR(5))
       ELSE CAST (COALESCE(CC_PTY_CD, '') AS CHAR(5)) 
   END OUDS_FAC_CD,

   CASE 
       WHEN GL_ACCT_NUM > ' ' THEN CAST (SUBSTR(GL_ACCT_NUM, 1, 12) AS CHAR(12)) 
       ELSE CAST (SAP_ACCT_NUM AS CHAR(12)) 
   END ACCT_NUM,

   CASE
       WHEN LE_PTY_CD > ' ' THEN CAST (LE_PTY_CD AS CHAR(4) )
       ELSE CAST (SUBSTR( COMP_PTY_CD, 1, 4) AS CHAR(4) )
   END COMP_PTY_CD,

   JE_LWR_TIER_RPTG_NUM, 
   LT2_NM, 

   CASE
       WHEN PRD_VAR_CD > ' ' THEN CAST (PRD_VAR_CD AS CHAR(3))
       ELSE CAST (COALESCE(FA_PTY_CD, '') AS CHAR(3))  
   END FA_PTY_CD,

   JE_LN_GLBL_CCY_CD, 
   JE_LN_LC_CD,

   CASE 
       WHEN GL_ACCT_LVL_NUM > ' ' THEN CAST(SUBSTR(GL_ACCT_LVL_NUM,1,10)  AS CHAR(11) ) 
       ELSE CAST(SUBSTR(FNCL_STMT_LN_NUM,1,11) AS CHAR(11) )
   END ACCT_LVL_NUM,

   SUM (JE_LN_GLBL_AMT) JE_LN_GLBL_AMT, 
   DDU_FAC_CD, 
   JE_HDR_DESC, 
   JE_HDR_NUM, 
   JE_GRP_NUM, 
   SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID
FROM   EDW_BI_SL_M1.BFV 
WHERE  CPC_PTY_CD = '00000000SX'
       AND TO_CHAR(RPTG_ACCTG_DT, 'YYYY')  >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS((CURRENT_DATE),-1),'YYYY')
       AND JE_VERS_NUM in ('200', '001') 
       AND SRC_LDGR_CD <> 'LG'
       AND ACCTG_PRD_MO_CD < 13
GROUP BY ABU_PTY_CD, ACCTG_PRD_YR_CD, ACCTG_PRD_MO_CD, OUDS_FAC_CD, ACCT_NUM, COMP_PTY_CD, JE_LWR_TIER_RPTG_NUM, 
LT2_NM, FA_PTY_CD, JE_LN_GLBL_CCY_CD, JE_LN_LC_CD, ACCT_LVL_NUM, JE_LN_GLBL_AMT, DDU_FAC_CD, JE_HDR_DESC, JE_HDR_NUM, JE_GRP_NUM, 
SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID;
```

**Error message:**

3504: selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Comment: Are you using Teradata or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You've included the column `JE_LN_GLBL_AMT` in your `GROUP BY` clause, but this is a summed value.

Comment: No, that is not the issue..I added that by mistake but I took off that now and its still not working..I was testing it piece by piece...I figured out what is causing the issue...CASE statements are causing issues..I am trying to rewrite the statement by using one more select outside this select and group by using the actual select...If you have any other ideas..please through your ideas here..Thanks

Comment: Oh, really? Wow, didn't know that about CASE statements. It sounds like you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aliases that you have created in this query in the same query's GROUP BY clause (at least in Oracle). You either have to use the expressions:

```
...
GROUP BY
CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(ABU_PTY_CD),4,2) AS CHAR(2)), 
..., 
CASE 
   WHEN GL_ACCT_LVL_NUM > ' ' THEN CAST(SUBSTR(GL_ACCT_LVL_NUM,1,10)  AS CHAR(11) ) 
   ELSE CAST(SUBSTR(FNCL_STMT_LN_NUM,1,11) AS CHAR(11) )
END, 
..., 
SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID
```

or create a subquery and then group by using your aliases:

```
SELECT ABU_PTY_CD, ...
FROM (
SELECT
   CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(ABU_PTY_CD),4,2) AS CHAR(2)) ABU_PTY_CD,
   ...
FROM   EDW_BI_SL_M1.BFV 
WHERE  CPC_PTY_CD = '00000000SX'
       AND TO_CHAR(RPTG_ACCTG_DT, 'YYYY')  >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS((CURRENT_DATE),-1),'YYYY')
       AND JE_VERS_NUM in ('200', '001') 
       AND SRC_LDGR_CD <> 'LG'
       AND ACCTG_PRD_MO_CD < 13
)
GROUP BY ABU_PTY_CD, ACCTG_PRD_YR_CD, ACCTG_PRD_MO_CD, OUDS_FAC_CD, ACCT_NUM, COMP_PTY_CD, JE_LWR_TIER_RPTG_NUM, 
LT2_NM, FA_PTY_CD, JE_LN_GLBL_CCY_CD, JE_LN_LC_CD, ACCT_LVL_NUM, JE_LN_GLBL_AMT, DDU_FAC_CD, JE_HDR_DESC, JE_HDR_NUM, JE_GRP_NUM, 
SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID;
```